# The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version

Tags: php, mysql, load-data-infile

Alright, so after a week of trying all the different ideas answers I have found with no success, I am going to ask.  This is for the LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE, for MySQL.  There have been many posts regarding this, but I am still unable to get it work from the web browser, but am able to run it from the mysql command prompt on the server, with the same user and pass connecting to the same database.  What I have tried so far

1. MySQL version 5.5
2. Ubuntu 12.04
3. PHP version 5.3

In my.cnf
`local-infile=1`
in mysqld,mysql,mysql-safe
`loose-local-infile=1` client

Restarted MySQL Server. At this point I was then able to run the query from the command prompt, and previously had not.
I have given the directory in which the files are being pulled from 777 access.
I have confirmed the php.ini has the local file parameter enabled.
I have updated apparmor.
Actual Query:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/var/www/ui/uploads/r_import.csv' INTO TABLE r_data FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 ROWS (first_name,last_name,apt,user_id)
```

Above query works from the mysql command with no special arguments in the connection to the server.

If anyone has anymore ideas on this, I would be happy to try anything....
Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
include 'includes/header.php';
if($_FILES['file']['type'] != "application/vnd.ms-excel"){
   die("This is not a CSV file.");
}
elseif(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])){
    $filename = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    copy( $filename, 'uploads/'.$name ) or die( "Could not copy file!");
    $file_to_import = '/var/www/ui/uploads/'.$name;
   $query = 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE  \''.$file_to_import.'\' INTO TABLE r_data FIELDS TERMINATED BY  \',\' ENCLOSED BY  \'"\' LINES TERMINATED BY  \'\n\' IGNORE 1 ROWS (first_name,last_name,apt,user_id)';
   echo $query;
   $result = mysqli_query($link,$query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
}
else{
   die("You shouldn't be here");
}
?>
```

Comment: where is your php code? what is your error message?

Comment: The error message is the title of the post.

Comment: Try to enable mysql general log and show full query.

Comment: See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data-local.html It shows how you can enable or disable this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$link = mysqli_init();
mysqli_options($link, MYSQLI_OPT_LOCAL_INFILE, true);
mysqli_real_connect($link, 'localhost', $username, $password, $database);
```

The connection string to the database is what worked for me.  I found it in the last comment in the link given by developerwjk

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the use of the `LOCAL` keyword. When you use `LOCAL` the server expects the MySQL client to read the file and send it. This applies when the client software is running on a remote machine, or when you're running the MySQL client on the server itself. (This is why you can run your query from the server command line).

If you're running PHP there is no client software involved. PHP makes calls directly to the server, so the `LOCAL` keyword is invalid in this context.

To use `LOAD DATA INFILE` from PHP you must make sure that the file is placed in a location *in the server filesystem* that the MySQL server has read access to, and that the full path to that file is passed as part of your query. Don't use the `LOCAL` keyword.

If you're trying to load a file from a remote client you'll need to upload the file to the file system first, then execute your query.

Note this sentence from the MySQL manual: *If LOCAL is specified, the file is read by the client program on the client host and sent to the server.*

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html

Comment: $link = mysqli_init();
mysqli_options($link, MYSQLI_OPT_LOCAL_INFILE, true);
mysqli_real_connect($link, 'localhost', $username, $password, $database); - changing the connection type as advised in one of the comments in the link given from  developerwjk solved my problem, but thanks for your time.