# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE : The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i'm getting this error when i'm trying  to run below LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE query .

i have checked

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'local_infile';
```

it is showing local_infile as ON

have granted all the needed permissions to database user

using `grant all privileges on DB Name .* to USER@localhost identified by "PASSWORD";`

PHP Version 5.4.45

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/var/www/vhosts/www.on-the-list.com/httpdocs/incoming/vehicles_imports/detroit_trading/dtcinventory.txt' INTO TABLE tbl_detriot FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' ' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY ' ' (third_party_id, condition1,vin,stock_number,year,make,model,trim,style,body_type,doors,drive_type,engine_block,engine_dis,fuel_type,fuel_des,transmission_type,transmission_speed, model_category,vehicle_type,vehicle_cat,city_mpg,hwy_mpg,selling_price,mileage,exterior_color,interior_color,options,comments,dealer_id,dealer_radius,certified,number_image,img,date_create,web_price,phone_ext,phone_pay,ppc_url,ppc_pay,delta_type,pre_quali)
```

Also when i try placing the query directly in phpmyadmin it works .

But when running it on php page it is giving error .
i have checked my db connections and db users FYI , everything is correct and cross checked many times .

Can anyone please help , what can be the problem .

Thanks for your help in advance .

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28550933/2298301) seems a bit similar. Does the solution proposed there look any relevant?

Comment: tried all the way no error , also no record got inserted .